# Merge [np-completeness] to [np-hardness]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Currently 50 questions are tagged as [[np-completeness](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/np-completeness)] and 20 questions as [[np-hardness](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/np-hardness)].  Among them, [7 questions are tagged as both](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/np-hardness+np-completeness).

I think that the difference of these two tags is too subtle for the distinction to be useful.  Therefore, I propose to merge [np-completeness] to [np-hardness].  Note the direction; I am proposing to make the *more popular tag* a synonym for the *less popular tag*, which is different from the usual proposal.

I know that NP-completeness and NP-hardness are two different notions.  However, in most cases, questions tagged as [np-completeness] ask whether a certain problem which is trivially in NP is NP-complete or not.  Therefore, the main point is whether the problem is NP-hard or not.  On the other hand, some of the questions tagged as [np-hardness] are about search or optimization problems, which are themselves not in NP (according to the standard definition of NP as a class of decision problems).  But the difference between search/optimization problems and decision problems is a technicality in most cases and should not be important in the classification of questions.

Some questions tagged as [np-hardness] ask about problems which are not known to be in NP.  Therefore, merging in the other direction would make the tag awkward for some questions.

What do you think?

---

*Update*: It has reached +4 with 4 upvotes and 0 downvotes, but there are two negative comments.  What should I do?  Let me clarify my points:

1. We should merge [np-completeness] and [np-hardness] into one tag because for most questions, their distinction depends not on the essence of a question but on a particular way a question is stated.
2. We should not merge them into [np-completeness] because there are rare cases where the [np-completeness] tag would be awkward.

If merging the two into the [np-hardness] tag is not desired, an alternative suggestion is to merge them into a new tag, for example [np-complete-np-hard].  But this is certainly clumsy.

Comment: I'd argue that np-completeness, while possibly less direct, is the more 'natural' tag.

Comment: I suggest keeping both tags.

Comment: @Suresh: I disagree.

Comment: I'll make the change shortly. To repeat: this change will remove np-completeness, merging it completely into np-hardness

Comment: @Suresh: Yes, that is my intent of this proposal.

Comment: @Suresh: By merge, I meant also creating a tag synonym, if it was not clear.

Comment: ah it wasn't, because these are two separate operations. I'll do that as well.

Comment: @Suresh: Thanks!